# What does homogeneous mean?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I saw this in an example problem:

> **Question:**
> **IV** *By substituting $y=tx$, when the equations are homogeneous in terms which contain $x$ and $y$*
>
> **(1)**\begin{align*} & 52x^2+7xy=5y^2\\ & 5x-3y=17\end{align*}
> \begin{align*} & \hspace{5mm}52x^2+7tx^2=5t^2x^2\\ & \hspace{5mm}5x-3tx=17\\ & \hspace{15mm}\vdots\end{align*}

I have two main questions:

1. How did the author know to substitute $y=tx$ here, and not try some other method
2. What in the world does "homogeneous" mean?!?

Google search says "homogeneous" in math means something with the same degree.

*Obviously, $x^2$ and $x$ are **not** the same degree*. So at this point, I am extra confused.

Comment: Can I have some context here. From which text did you get the example?

Comment: All of $x^2,xy,y^2$ have degree $2$ as [monomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial#Degree).

Comment: @MiguelAngelAlarconBustos From *A Synopsis of Elementary Results and Applied Mathematics*

Comment: @dxiv So $x^5+4x^3uy+6y^5$ a homogeneous polynomial?

Comment: If you consider it as a polynomial in $x, u, y$ then [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial).

Comment: @dxiv Then what does it mean in other context? The same thing? For example, the number of homogeneous products of $r$ dimensions of $n$ things is $$H(n,r)=\frac {n(n+1)(n+2)\ldots (n+r-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot r}$$

Comment: Sorry, no idea what that other context is. Doesn't look like a polynomial for sure, and by the little you quote it doesn't claim to be one either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the term 7xy of your first equation as an example.

Degree (7xy) = degree (xy) = degree(x) + degree(y) = 1 + 1 = 2.

The degrees of all other terms are calculated in such manner. Since all of them are of degree 2, we can say that the equation is homogeneous in degree 2.